# Getting values from imported dictionary

Tags: python

Lets say I have a file named tools.py. From tools.py I have a dictionary with sample key/value pairs:

```
TOOLS ={0x100: "Hammer",
    0x101: "Screw",
    0x102: "Nail",
    0x103: "Wedge",
    0x104: "Drill",
    0x105: "Socket",
    }
```

I have another file named file.py where I import tools.py. I have a value of 0x101 and I want to access tools.py dictionary TOOLS such that I can create a new dictionary with 0x101 key being Screw. In other words I have defined

```
import tools
value = 10
placeholder = 0x101
new_dict = {}
```

I want to add the entry Screw:10 by looking up 0x101 in tools.py and getting the value Screw. How do I do this in python?

Comment: Did you mean `{TAGS : {...`?

Comment: Edited. Was changing up an example and accidentally left the name in.

Comment: How about `new_dict[TOOLS[placeholder]] = value`?

Comment: For some reason I get a: name 'TOOLS' is not defined error

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it as an answer:

```
import tools
new_dict[tools.TOOLS[placeholder]] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it with the format that you had, if you want to add more to the dictionary.

```
from tools import TOOLS
value = 10
placeholder = 0x101
new_dict = {}
new_dict.update({TOOLS[placeholder]: value})
print(new_dict)
```

This way, you look up the placeholder you had in TOOLS, and use it as a key in the new_dict. For the value, you use your "value" variable.